# Intellij IDEA and SBT syntax error

Tags: scala, intellij-idea, sbt

I am newbie in scala and SBT 
I started using IDEA with SBT and faced unclear error (Expression type DslEntry must conform to Def.SettingsDefinition in SBT file) 
[image] 
It's very simple empty test project with jetty plugin (example taken from plugin site)

here's plugins.sbt source:

```
logLevel := Level.Warn

addSbtPlugin("com.earldouglas" % "xsbt-web-plugin" % "2.1.0")
```

This error is present only in IDEA GUI. If I compile project - all fine. from console - all fine. 
But I do not like when something does not work properly

I tried to download last version of SBT and set path to it in global IDEA properties - the problem persists.

I downloaded last intellij IDEA EAP with last version of scala plugin, sbt plugin and another plugins - the problem persists.

Can anyone help to solve this issue? 
 Thanks

Comment: Look at the right side of idea, open SBT tab, select main project and refresh it.

Comment: I did it many...many times =)))

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Intellij sbt sbt-native-packager and enablePlugins error](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31552605/intellij-sbt-sbt-native-packager-and-enableplugins-error)

Answer (score 17, accepted):

Try this:

```
lazy val root = (project in file(".")).
  enablePlugins(JettyPlugin).
  settings(
    name := "test",
    scalaVersion := "2.11.7",
    version := "1.0"
  )
```

Updates:
The followings are what I know:

The error comes from intellij's sbt plugin https://github.com/JetBrains/intellij-sbt/blob/master/idea-plugin/src/main/scala/org/jetbrains/sbt/language/SbtAnnotator.scala#L41.

The return type of `(project in file(".")).
      enablePlugins(JettyPlugin)` is `Project`. It is acceptable by sbt plugin.

However, if you use standalone `enablePlugins(JettyPlugin)`, the return type is **different**, and it becomes `DslEntry` which makes the sbt plugin unhappy. Another way to workaround with that is simply to consume the return type of `enablePlugins`. For example:

```
val foo = enablePlugins(JettyPlugin)
```

Comment: would you add an explanation to the solution?

Comment: @Marin I don't have a crystal understanding of this puzzle. But I updated the answer with what I know.

Comment: @SexyNerd Somehow assigning `enablePlugins` to a val actually does not enable the plugin. The wiggly line is gone, however no plugin enabled.

Answer (score 1):

This is an issue with the IntelliJ Scala plugin and will be fixed in an upcoming version: https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/SCL-8413

Comment: I'm still seeing the error in my project/plugins.sbt and project/assembly.sbt files.