# Expression type DslEntry must conform to Def.SettingsDefinition in SBT file at line enablePlugins(JavaServerAppPackaging)

Tags: intellij-idea, sbt

I get the message `Expression type DslEntry must conform to Def.SettingsDefinition in SBT file` at line `enablePlugins(JavaServerAppPackaging)` i tried refreshing the project but it didn't help. The whole sbt file is mostly generated by the lightbend (former typesafe) activator and looks as follows

```
import NativePackagerHelper._

name := """ping-backend"""

version := "2.4.0"

scalaVersion := "2.11.7"

libraryDependencies ++= Seq(
  "com.typesafe.akka" %% "akka-actor" % "2.4.0",
  "com.typesafe.play" %% "play-json" % "2.4.6",
  "org.igniterealtime.smack" % "smack-java7" % "4.1.0",
  "org.igniterealtime.smack" % "smack-tcp" % "4.1.0",
  "org.igniterealtime.smack" % "smack-im" % "4.1.0",
  "org.igniterealtime.smack" % "smack-extensions" % "4.1.0"
)

enablePlugins(JavaServerAppPackaging)

mainClass in Compile := Some("sample.hello.Main")

mappings in Universal ++= {
  // optional example illustrating how to copy additional directory
  directory("scripts") ++
  // copy configuration files to config directory
  contentOf("src/main/resources").toMap.mapValues("config/" + _)
}

// add 'config' directory first in the classpath of the start script,
// an alternative is to set the config file locations via CLI parameters
// when starting the application
scriptClasspath := Seq("../config/") ++ scriptClasspath.value
```

when running `activator run` or `sbt run` in the command line the project runs. I can even build and run it from Intellij, so this is more of an inconvenience then an error, but I would still rather have it resolved. Can someone help me with this?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Intellij sbt sbt-native-packager and enablePlugins error](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31552605/intellij-sbt-sbt-native-packager-and-enableplugins-error)

Comment: Still around in 2021, and there's no light at the end of the tunnel. Their QA dept should have been sacked long ago (I've talked to them several times, and they are clueless).

Answer (score 7):

I closed project by *File -> close project* option and removed all `project/`, `target/` and `.idea/` from main and sub projects. Then, I reopened intelliJ and made a fresh import by *File -> New -> Project from existing sources -> import project from external model -> select project directory -> sbt*.

I believe the issue happened for wrong way of import. Correct way of import fixed it.

Answer (score 1):

The error comes from intellij's sbt plugin https://github.com/JetBrains/intellij-sbt/blob/master/idea-plugin/src/main/scala/org/jetbrains/sbt/language/SbtAnnotator.scala#L41.

try this

```
lazy val root = (project in file("."))
  .disablePlugins(JavaServerAppPackaging)
```

or this

```
val foo = disablePlugins(JavaServerAppPackaging)
```