# How to force a specific version of dependency?

Tags: sbt

A dependency `bar` depends on `foo` 1.2.3, but that version of `foo` has a bug and I need to use version 1.2.2.

I can do that with `force()`.

```
libraryDependencies += "foo" %% "foo" % "1.2.2" force()
```

That method is not recommended by the [docs](http://www.scala-sbt.org/0.13/docs/Library-Management.html):

> Forcing a revision (Not recommended)
>
> Note: Forcing can create logical inconsistencies so it’s no longer recommended.

Does this mean SBT has a different, better way than `force()` to use a specific version of a dependency? If so, what?

Or am I to infer from the documentation that this entire problem is one that I'm recommended not to have?

Answer (score 71, accepted):

you can use [dependencyOverrides](https://www.scala-sbt.org/1.x/docs/Library-Management.html#Overriding+a+version):

```
dependencyOverrides += "foo" %% "foo" % "1.2.2"
```

You're not avoiding "logical inconsistencies" anyway. If you force a version, you have to manually take care of compatibility with other libraries, there's no way out of that.

From the documentation:

> Overriding a version
>
> For binary compatible conflicts, sbt provides dependency overrides.
>   They are configured with the dependencyOverrides setting, which is a
>   set of ModuleIDs. For example, the following dependency definitions
>   conflict because spark uses log4j 1.2.16 and scalaxb uses log4j
>   1.2.17:
>
> ```
> libraryDependencies ++= Seq(
>   "org.spark-project" %% "spark-core" % "0.5.1",    
>   "org.scalaxb" %% "scalaxb" % "1.0.0" )
> ```
>
> The default conflict manager chooses the latest revision of log4j, 1.2.17:
>
> ```
> show update 
> [info] compile: 
> [info]    log4j:log4j:1.2.17: ... ... 
> [info]    (EVICTED) log4j:log4j:1.2.16 ...
> ```
>
> To change the version
>   selected, add an override:
>
> ```
> dependencyOverrides += "log4j" % "log4j" % "1.2.16"
> ```

Comment: don't forget about this tine remark at the end


```Note: this is an Ivy-only feature and will not be included in a published pom.xml.```

Comment: Try `libraryDependencies := Set()`

Comment: `dependencyOverrides ++= Set(... foo ...)`

Comment: If that's not working for anybody, try adding dependencyOverrides += "...foo.. " much like in this manner: https://stackoverflow.com/a/37966356/7082628

Comment: @EugenePlatonov, and that's okay. It would be confusing with multiple overrides; I just need an escape hatch.

Comment: Where should we add dependencyOverrides? After the library dependencies or before them one we want to override version of one of transitive dependency coming from another dependency. This is relatd to log4j issue on scala spark projects.