# Override a version of transitive dependency in sbt

Tags: sbt, sbt-assembly, sbt-plugin

I have a requirement to override a transitive dependency to a later version of the same.

In maven I can do this by simply adding the overriding one on top.

```
  <dependencies>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>com.fasterxml.jackson.core</groupId>
      <artifactId>jackson-databind</artifactId>
      <version>2.8.9</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>com.fasterxml.jackson.core</groupId>
      <artifactId>jackson-annotations</artifactId>
      <version>2.8.9</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>com.fasterxml.jackson.module</groupId>
      <artifactId>jackson-module-scala_2.11</artifactId>
      <version>2.8.9</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>org.apache.spark</groupId>
      <artifactId>spark-core_${scala.version.dist}</artifactId>
      <version>${spark.version}</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>com.mypackage.road</groupId>
      <artifactId>package-that-contains-transitive-deps</artifactId>
      <version>4.2.0</version>
    </dependency>
```

How can i do this in sbt? Also like the GUI that is available in maven (Dependency-Hierarchy tab) which shows which jars are overriding the others, how can i see that in sbt?

I have already tried to force the versions I want using dependencyOverrides. But the issue is still there.So how can I check that the older version is exactly evicted by the version I am overriding. sbt dependencyTree is not showing that the newer one has evicted the transitive dependency.

Comment: There is a nice sbt plugin for checking which dependencies are evicted in favor of which version: [sbt-dependency-graph](https://github.com/jrudolph/sbt-dependency-graph)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can override versions using `dependencyOverrides` setting (see [linked answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/36501752/736957)).

Then you normally see evicted versions during `update`. But if for some reason you don't, you can run `show evicted` in sbt to output eviction warnings. Example output:

```
...
[warn] Found version conflict(s) in library dependencies; some are suspected to be binary incompatible:
[warn]  * org.scalameta:inputs_2.12:2.1.2 is selected over 2.0.0-M3
[warn]      +- org.scalameta:scalameta_2.12:2.1.2                 (depends on 2.1.2)
[warn]      +- org.scalameta:quasiquotes_2.12:2.1.2               (depends on 2.1.2)
...
[warn] Run 'evicted' to see detailed eviction warnings
[info] Here are other depedency conflicts that were resolved:
[info]  * com.trueaccord.scalapb:scalapb-runtime_2.12:0.6.6 is selected over 0.6.2
[info]      +- org.scalameta:langmeta_2.12:2.1.2                  (depends on 0.6.2)
[info]      +- org.scalameta:metals_2.12:0.1-SNAPSHOT             (depends on 0.6.2)
[info]  * com.lihaoyi:sourcecode_2.12:0.1.4 is selected over 0.1.3
[info]      +- com.lihaoyi:fansi_2.12:0.2.5                       (depends on 0.1.4)
[info]      +- com.lihaoyi:fastparse-utils_2.12:0.4.4             
...
```