# Sbt Uber Jar assemblyMergeStrategy

Tags: sbt, sbt-assembly

I am building a tool that I will deploy in an Uber jar using `addSbtPlugin("com.eed3si9n" % "sbt-assembly" % "0.14.6")`

The merge strategies confuse me. ([see https://github.com/sbt/sbt-assembly](http://see%20https://github.com/sbt/sbt-assembly)). Rather than specifying which *version* of duplicate dependencies to keep (or instructing to keep latest version), the compiler picks which to keep or discard based on position in the CP.

Based on previous experience, this seems to invite problems. How do I specify which version of, say, Jackson or Slf4j I want to keep?

Comment: Yes, I agree the answer appears to be a duplicate, but my point of entry was assemblyMergeStrategy, so people may search for this question and then link to the fuller answer in the original question

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you just want to pick a version, use [`dependencyOverrides`](https://www.scala-sbt.org/1.x/docs/Library-Management.html#Overriding+a+version). You can also inspect version conflicts via `show evicted` command. See [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/36501752/736957) for a related answer.